No textures, shading, surfaces are being exported to gltf
I am using blender - for the first time/newbie - (version 4.2.2) and downloaded a blender file from https://www.blendswap.com/blend/14371.
This file contains a collection of objects used to draw the keyboard which should look like this
I opened the blender project which contains all of the individual keys, connectors etc

I am trying to export to gltf so that the surfaces, colors and shadows are all preserved.
When I export the using the gltf2.0 exporter I get a blank/white render with non of the detail:


What I have tried:

read https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html

tried the suggestions here: https://iconscout.com/blog/export-gltf-files-from-blender

and here: https://docs.zap.works/designer/3d/exporting-3d-models/

I have converted all objects in the collection to mesh by selecting the collection and right click > convert to mesh

As per the blogs and manual, I have selected one object/layer as a test and ensured that it is principled BSDF


but when I export it there is no text, shadow, nothing only a white frame. The base color does change if I change it to another color - without the shading.


On export I've tried glb/gltf separate/gltf embedded and all with the same result.



What do I need to do or am I missing to render something like the image above with the colors, shading etc?
